# SAP TCODE Extraction tool request

Tags: sap-gui, sap-basis

I have a requirement to get the result of different Transaction codes (TCodes), that extract has to be loaded into an SQL database. There are some TCODEs with complex logic, so replicate the logic is not an option.

Is there any way to have a daily basis process that runs all the tcodes and locates the extract in a onedrive or any other location?

I just need the same result as if a user get into the tcode, executes, and extract to a CSV file.

Comment: Lot of information about the context is missing here. Do you want to create a program (which programming language? what did you try?), or are looking for an existing software to do that for you?

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for options. I need to integrate Power BI with the result data of these TCODES. I hope it clarifies. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: There is no way to do what you are asking. a Tcode is an application. So imagine writing a program that runs every application on your windows desktop and send results to csv file. do they give a result? not without doing anything, so that is why your request does not make sense. Since you mention Power BI then you might be talking specifically about reports in SAP, these can be accessed using a tcode but not all of them are, anyways you will need a SAP comrade to set this up for you.

Good luck

Comment: Don't waste time on this. Ask your SAP team to write the result into a CSV. Use your Power BI to read CSV. This is the most efficient and cost-effective way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks both for your comments, really helps!  Let me see if I get it, it is possible to ask SAP team to run the result of any TCODE in a CSV file in a specific location and then pick ti up with Power BI (there is no feature in SAP, should be a custom solution). Am I right? This solution, can be apply to any TCODE, right?. To be honest, when I asked SAP team, they say that the logic of each TCODE is sooo complex and it will take too much time to do it (I guess they whant to do a process that replicates the logic of the tcode, but that is not what I'm looking for). Thanks for your time!

Comment: SAPGui scripting is your friend https://blogs.sap.com/2012/10/08/introduction-to-sap-gui-scripting/